# post array of objects to mvc controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'n using ajax post to controller in mvc4,

my code controller is :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateAllSettings(int PresetID,List<CustomerAjaxServiceSettingPoco> customerServiceSettings)
{
```

and CustomerAjaxServiceSettingPoco is:

```
 public class CustomerAjaxServiceSettingPoco
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string ClientSettingValue { get; set; }
    }
```

my javascript is :

```
 var customerServiceSettings = new Array();
        $('.settings_user').each(function () {
            customerServiceSettings[customerServiceSettings.length] = { 'ID': $(this).data('settingsid'), 'ClientSettingValue': $(this).val() };
        });



$.ajax({
        url: '/Services/UpdateAllSettings?PresetID=' + PresetID,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'customerServiceSettings':JSON.stringify( customerServiceSettings) },
        traditional: true,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {
            do...
        }
    });
```

still in debug mode I get "customerServiceSettings count=0" and "PresetID = 1"
what am I doing wrong ? 
in fire bug the post source is :
parameters 
customerServiceSettings [{"ID":1,"ClientSettingValue":"False"},{"ID":2,"ClientSettingValue":"False"},{"ID":3,"ClientSettingValue":"False"},{"ID":4,"ClientSettingValue":"False"},{"ID":5,"ClientSettingValue":"True"},{"ID":6,"ClientSettingValue":"True"},{"ID":9,"ClientSettingValue":"True"},{"ID":10,"ClientSettingValue":"False"},{"ID":11,"ClientSettingValue":"True"},{"ID":12,"ClientSettingValue":"True"},{"ID":13,"ClientSettingValue":"False"},{"ID":14,"ClientSettingValue":"True"},{"ID":15,"ClientSettingValue":"True"},{"ID":67,"ClientSettingValue":""},{"ID":68,"ClientSettingValue":""},{"ID":69,"ClientSettingValue":""},{"ID":70,"ClientSettingValue":""},{"ID":21,"ClientSettingValue":"True"},{"ID":22,"ClientSettingValue":"True"},{"ID":23,"ClientSettingValue":"False"},{"ID":24,"ClientSettingValue":"True"},{"ID":25,"ClientSettingValue":"False"},{"ID":27,"ClientSettingValue":"False"},{"ID":28,"ClientSettingValue":"False"},{"ID":71,"ClientSettingValue":""},{"ID":72,"ClientSettingValue":""}]
Source
customerServiceSettings=%5B%7B%22ID%22%3A1%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22False%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A2%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22False%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A3%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22False%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A4%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22False%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A5%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22True%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A6%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22True%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A9%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22True%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A10%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22False%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A11%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22True%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A12%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22True%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A13%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22False%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A14%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22True%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A15%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22True%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A67%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A68%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A69%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A70%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A21%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22True%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A22%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22True%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A23%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22False%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A24%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22True%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A25%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22False%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A27%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22False%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A28%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22False%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A71%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22%22%7D%2C%7B%22ID%22%3A72%2C%22ClientSettingValue%22%3A%22%22%7D%5D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try add **contentType** and `stringify` whole object, something like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '...',
        data: JSON.stringify({ steps: ['1', '2', '3'] }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
});
```